# My Math.random() method always return with 1 ? WHy?

Tags: java

There are 3 marbles randomly generated and i'll compare them if they are same,different or one is different. My code is below and my question is above...  can u help me out ?

```
public static void marb(){
    int a[],b[];
    int num=0;

    a=new int[3];
    b=new int[3];

    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    a[2]=3;

    **num=(int)Math.random();** //num is always assigned  1

    for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        num=(int)Math.random();

        b[x]=a[num];

        System.out.println(""+x+". marble:"+b[x]);      

    }

    int x=0;

    if(b[x]==b[x+1] && b[x+1]==b[x+2])
        System.out.println("ALL SAME");
    else if(b[x]!=b[x+1] && b[x]!=b[x+2] && b[x+1]!=b[x+2])
        System.out.println("ALL DIFFERENT");
    else
        System.out.println("One is different");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of the random number generator

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

which also seeds the generator.

Then call

```
int myrandnum = rand.nextInt();
```

Subsequent calls to the `nextInt` method will generate a different number.

Answer (score 12):

`Math.random()` returns a *double* between `0` and `1`.  Casting to `int` will always truncate to `0`.

If you want a random integer use the `Random.nextInt(range)` method.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that `(int) Math.random()` always returns 1? If you told us that it always returns 0, I would believe that immediately.

`Math.random()` returns a `double` in the range `[0;1)`. The conversion from `double` to `int` truncates the number, to it is always 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` returns a `double` >= 0 and < 1. If you want a random number between 0 and x, use `(int)(Math.random() * x)`.

Comment: No, you should rather get your own random number generator and then use `rnd.nextInt(x)`. Otherwise not all outcomes are equally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Because Math.random returns a value between 0 and 1 (either double or float I guess). Casting it to an int it loses the value after the decimal point and I guess casting rounds up to 1.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use Math.Random() is to multiple it by the uppermost number that you want, then close the parenthesis and cast it to an int (if needed)

**int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random()*max)**

Its the placement of the parenthesis that you are off on. Math.random is a great function to use when you have an upper bounds for the range of numbers that you want. There is another stack overflow answer on getting it to work with a lower bounds as well, for a range of numbers from a min to a max.

Click here: [Math.random() explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Answer (score 0):

> My Math.random() method always return with 1

Well, this isn't true- in that case it always returns 0, which is used as *num* but what happens next:

```
b[x]=a[num];
```

you call a[0] three times as b[0], b[1] and b[2] and since you hardcoded

```
a[0]=1;
```

you'll get only that value.
In given example you can try

```
num=(int)(Math.random()*3);
```

as it simply generates random int from 0 to 2 or even use

```
num=(int)(Math.random()*a.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Java programmer but I have some idea of it.
Math.random() will produce random numbers between 0 and 1. Casting to int means you want either **1** or **2**.
Since you are getting only 1, Math.random() just happens to be producing numbers between 0.5 and 1, that's all.
I also know that if you run the program again and again, it will produce the same set of pseudorandom values (except maybe you recompile).

Comment: -1: Why would casting a number between 0.0 and 1.0 give you either 1 or 2 as an output?