# Math.random() explanation

Tags: java, math

This is a pretty simple Java (though probably applicable to all programming) question:

> `Math.random()` returns a number between zero and one.

If I want to return an integer between zero and hundred, I would do:

```
(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
```

Between one and hundred, I would do:

```
(int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)
```

But what if I wanted to get a number between three and five? Will it be like following statement:

```
(int) Math.random() * 5 + 3
```

I know about `nextInt()` in `java.lang.util.Random`. But I want to learn how to do this with `Math.random()`.

Comment: For [3,5]: `(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 3`

Comment: BTW: the range is from 0.0 inclusive to 1.0 exclusive (you won't actaully get 1.0 ever)  Using nextInt() is a far better choice, not only is it simpler but also much faster.

Comment: Using `Math.ceil` is wrong, it gives the wrong result when `Math.random()` returns `0`.

Comment: What if Math.floor returns 0.029? How to always get a two digit number with a single statement?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max)
{
   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

Output of `randomWithRange(2, 5)` 10 times:

```
5
2
3
3
2
4
4
4
5
4
```

The bounds are inclusive, ie [2,5], and `min` must be less than `max` in the above example.

**EDIT:** If someone was going to try and be stupid and reverse `min` and `max`, you could change the code to:

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max)
{
   int range = Math.abs(max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + (min <= max ? min : max);
}
```

**EDIT2:** For your question about `double`s, it's just:

```
double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
{
   double range = (max - min);     
   return (Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

And again if you want to idiot-proof it it's just:

```
double randomWithRange(double min, double max)
{
   double range = Math.abs(max - min);     
   return (Math.random() * range) + (min <= max ? min : max);
}
```

Comment: What if you don't use `(int)` and want it to return a `double`?

Comment: If you want double then just replace the `int`s with `double`s (and the typecast is unnecessary). I assumed you wanted `int`s but I'll add to my post.

Comment: Actually with `double`s remove the `+ 1` also since `Math.random()` isn't being truncated. However, the range will be [min, max) since `Math.random` "Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0." There'd be a very minimal chance of the number being exactly `max` anyway even if it was possible.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to generate a number from 0 to 100, then your code would look like this:

```
(int)(Math.random() * 101);
```

To generate a number from 10 to 20 :

```
(int)(Math.random() * 11 + 10);
```

In the general case:

```
(int)(Math.random() * ((upperbound - lowerbound) + 1) + lowerbound);
```

(where `lowerbound` is inclusive and `upperbound` exclusive).

The inclusion or exclusion of `upperbound` depends on your choice.
Let's say `range = (upperbound - lowerbound) + 1` then `upperbound` is inclusive, but if `range = (upperbound - lowerbound)` then `upperbound` is exclusive.

Example: If I want an integer between 3-5, then if range is (5-3)+1 then 5 is inclusive, but if range is just (5-3) then 5 is exclusive.

Comment: `upperbound` exclusive? I think it'll be inclusive.

Comment: @vidit it's exclusive

Comment: don't think you're gettin the big picture upperbound can be either, as provided in the example

Answer (score 19):

The [`Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class of Java located in the `java.util` package will serve your purpose better. It has some [`nextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) methods that return an integer. The one taking an int argument will generate a number between 0 and that int, the latter not inclusive.

Comment: I updated my question, I'd like to know how to do it with `Math.random()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a number between 10 to 20 inclusive, you can use `java.util.Random`

```
int myNumber = new Random().nextInt(11) + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method which receives boundaries and returns a random integer. It is slightly more advanced (completely universal): boundaries can be **both positive and negative**, and minimum/maximum boundaries can come in any order.

```
int myRand(int i_from, int i_to) {
  return (int)(Math.random() * (Math.abs(i_from - i_to) + 1)) + Math.min(i_from, i_to);
}
```

In general, it finds the absolute distance between the borders, gets relevant random value, and then shifts the answer based on the bottom border.