# How do you generate a random number between [1, n] using a random generator that generates a floating point number between [0.0, 1.0)

Tags: algorithm, math, random

Suppose you have a random number generator that generates a random floating point number between [0.0, 1.0) such as `drand48`, how can you create a random number generator that generates an integer between [1, n].

Comment: I think `drand48` generates a number from [0,1] and not [0,1), so what do you really have? Yes, this makes a difference.

Comment: Perhaps an underlying assumption that the distribution should be uniform is worth explicitly stating (or denying).  While the Open Group documents [the range of drand48](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/drand48.html) as uniform on [0.0,1.0], the corresponding probability of returning 1.0 is negligible.  For sake of exactitude we might call `drand48` until a result less than 1.0 is obtained.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math.random() explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiply by `n`, take the floor, and add 1.

Comment: Since the input is always positive and the output is to be an integer, casting to `int` would be better than using `floor`.

Comment: @Jason please what do you mean  'take the floor' i'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: @oussama: The floor of a number x is the largest integer n such that n <= x.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand this is equivalent to n = (long)x in C, that's right?

Comment: @oussama: Sorry, I don't know C well enough to answer that, so I'll let someone else do that. (In particular, I don't know what happens if x < 0.) Anyhow, surely you have access to a math library with the usual floor, ceil, and round functions?

Comment: Casting float or double to integral types truncates, so it gives floor for x >= 0 and ceiling for x <= 0.

Answer (score 0):

Take the result of the RNG, multiply by n-1 and add 1.

Comment: Since 1.0 is not included, `n` would be a better factor.

Answer (score -2):

Example in c:

```
long rand(int n)
{
    double rand1 = 0;

    rand1 = drand48();
    rand1 *= n - 1;
    rand1 += 1;

    return  (long)rand1;
}
```

Comment: Your code has the disadvantage of not being a linear (or at least monotonic) transformation. But besides this minor flaw it is even incorrect for not guaranteeing [ **1**,n].

Comment: It can produce 0 for any sufficiently small `rand1`.

Comment: In case of using `drand48` (which generates [0,1], although the OP asked for [0,1), but then he also referenced `drand48`), multiplying by `n-1` and adding 1 would be a better idea. Though it would be biased a bit to the lower end, but it would at least be monotonic and from [1,n].

Comment: Your update can now produce `2n-1` for any sufficiently large `rand1`. Just get rid of this if and do a simple linear transformation and remember that `rand1` is a double from [0,1].

Comment: Now it's correct, though using double literals instead of integers would be cleaner, but nevermind. But my down-vote stays, as it was an incorrect answer for too long a time and required extensive help (actually sufficient for its own question) to get corrected.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can have different random number generators.

```
Multiply by n, take the int, and add 1.
```

Comment: Incomplete answer! "OR" what?

Comment: I am sorry, I was writing something different.

Comment: And I hope that perfect literal quote from another answer is just by conincidence!

Comment: Yes. He beat me by 1 sec. I was thinking the same.

Comment: Why did you cut-and-paste my answer?

Comment: @klm9971 So it was really a half-answer to be first and to be updated with more information later? And did you really think the the exact same words? And I don't really understand your second solution, anyway? Take the double? Do you mean multiply by 2?

Comment: @Jason: : It happens that your answer and mine were the same. Didnt mean to copy your ans.

Comment: It is interesting that both users employ the Oxford comma.

Comment: @klm9971: There is no way that's believable.