# Random generator in java with selections menu

Tags: java, arrays

How can I assign a specific value to a string without using arrays or enumerations?

Example: 1 for "king", 2 for "queen" 3 for "guard". And then use random generator to generate between 1 and 3.

Comment: This is a strange requirement, but how about `select(val) case 1:.. case2:...`?

Comment: You can use `Map<Integer,String>` or just `List<String>` but I am curious why `String[]` is not allowed...

Comment: Vectors don't count as arrays in my book. Can you use those?

Comment: it like pointing a value to a string without arrays

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete select case approach:

```
public static String toName(int value) {
  select(value) {
    case 1: return "king";
    case 2: return "queen";
    case 3: return "guard";
  }
  return null; //no matched value
}
```

Then borrowing [this `randomWithRange()` from AusCBloke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961881/16959) you can use it like this:

```
System.out.println(toName(randomWithRange(1,3)));
```

Comment: my eyes are on fire... static method, non-final input arguments, string literals, and return null?

Comment: It made feel a bit dirty to write as well, I would love to understand why arrays are to be avoided

Comment: So how do i use the random generator for these three case and compare to the user's answer

Comment: `Math.random() * ( maxVal - minVal )`

Comment: The problem is that i got a program where they ask me to "link" a integer to a string like i said before and then ask the user to guess what is the word for example king, queen or quard. if the user enter queen then quit the program else ask him again about three time.

Comment: maybe look into using a `HashMap`, it's keyed by default (you can use numbers or whatever), and then store the data associated with it. Then use a key (your number) and it will return the data associated with it.