# How to get a random integer in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a random integer, but the way I'm doing it takes a really long time to get that random number ( like 10 seconds!)

```
Random generator=new Random();
do {
    id=generator.nextInt();
}
while(id<=0||id>=4);
```

I'm trying to get a random number between (and include) 0 to 4
This code so far gets the job done, but 10 seconds is too long!

what is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the configuration of you machine?

Comment: you dont need `while(id<=0||id>=4)` to check, simply specify the range `generator.nextInt(5);`

Comment: i think this would help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want

```
generator.nextInt(5);
```

which returns a random integer between 0 and 4.  The reason why your original code took so long was because it was generating random integers over and over, until it got one between 1 and 3.

Note that as you were throwing away everything 0 or less, and everything 4 or more, you weren't even getting the range that you expected.

More information on the methods of the `Random` class can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: +1 for link to documentation without succumbing to the temptation to be snarky or condescending.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're generating literally probably billions of random numbers and throwing them away until you get one between 0 and 4. Instead:

```
id = generator.nextInt(5); // number between 0 and 4, inclusive
```

In the future, please read the documentation for the classes you're using; this is [clearly explained in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Math.random(**)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)   cast it into `int`

```
int i=(int)Math.random()*4;
```

Comment: Better to use the built-in `nextInt(int)` method. It's more transparent and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the upper bound (assuming you want 1, 2, or 3):

```
id = 1 + generator.nextInt(3);
```

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> public int nextInt(int n)
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(4);
```