# Pick a random element from a string array?

Tags: java, arrays

I've got this code, which (I hope) reads from a text file with 66 words and puts the words into an array.

```
BufferedReader buff = null;
String wordlist=new String[66];
int i=0;

try {
    buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\easy.txt"));
    wordlist[i] = buff.readLine();
    while(wordlist[i] != null&i<66){
        wordlist[i]=buff.readLine();
        i++;
    }
}
```

I want to pick a random word from the array. However trying a few things myself and looking at other questions doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried and in what way it 'doesn't seem to work'?

Comment: `wordList[new Random().nextInt(wordList.length)]`?

Comment: short answer: yes - long answer: use `Math.random()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained

Answer (score 18):

The simplest code IMHO would be:

```
String word = wordlist[new Random().nextInt(wordlist.length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
String randomString = wordlist[(int)(Math.random() * wordlist.length)];
```

Comment: I've learned since posting this answer about the difference between Math.random() vs. Random.nextInt(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738629/math-random-versus-random-nextintint

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. I've set it to display the word that it picked on a label and all it says "null". I've got all the code on the same button, so that possibly has something to do with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This code definitely works. You might be having an issue if you're using a variable inside the action listener of your button that you have declared outside of your button, but without seeing your code, I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number between 0 and 65, and then use that number as the index of which String you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a random number generator (an instance of Random).

Then you call the method nextInt(wordList.length) to get a random index on your array of string.

For example:

Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(wordList.length);

Then:    wordList[index]  to get the randomly selected string.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to is to select a random number from the wordlist array by doing
    `String = randomWord = wordlist[(int)Math.random() * wordlist.length]`
or 
    `String randomWord = wordlist[(int)Math.random() * 66]`