# Shuffle random string from arraylist?

Tags: arraylist

I have an arrayList where I have entered some strings (names). The assignment is pretty simple but I have no idea how to do it. We have to make a program that will print out a random String in the console from the list.

I've come this far:

```
ArrayList <String> p = new ArrayList <String> ();
Random ran = new Random ();

p.add("Petter");
p.add("Per");
p.add("Mohammed");

System.out.println(p.get(ran.next));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pick a random element from a string array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150199/pick-a-random-element-from-a-string-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Collection.shuffle(p);
System.out.println(p.get(0));
```

Comment: That will be unnecessarily inefficient. There is no need to shuffle entire collection when you just want to choose random element.