# random number ranges from 1-8 with a desired output of 1,1,2,2,4,4,3,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8?

Tags: java, arrays

i have this problem on how to generate a random number with a range of 1 - 8, i only needed 2 pairs of these number not 1,1,1 or 3,3,3. here are my codes i already imported java.util.random:

```
          int[][] displayArray = new int[4][4];
        int[][] fieldArray = new int[4][4];

        //generates random Values where "i" represents rows and "j" represents columns
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray.length; j++) {
                fieldArray[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 8); //generates table with randomized numbers.
            }
        }

        //Print the values
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {          
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray.length; j++) {
                 System.out.print("[" + fieldArray[i][j] + "]" + "\t");                     
                }
       // Every time we finish printing a row we jump to the next line.
            System.out.print("\n");
            }

  }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please update the question.

Comment: Try Random, this is a good place to start [Math Random - Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast if you were to look in his code, you would see that he is using random. His problem is that he doesn't want the third row of integers.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray.length; j++) {
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray[i].length; j++) {
```

in both places. Also, I would prefer

```
Random rand = new Random();
int val = rand.nextInt(8) + 1; // <-- a random number between 1 and 8.
```

but with `Math.random()` you would also need to add `+ 1` because you'll include 0 (and exclude 8),

```
fieldArray[i][j] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You don't want to have random numbers, but rather a random order of your numbers**. `Collections.shuffle()` offers a method do do that (randomize order in a `List`).

This code works with any quad size (>0), creating a quadradic array filled with numbers, beginning with 1, containing each number twice, if possible (for odd quad sizes you get an odd amount of numbers):

```
    int quadSize = 4; //4x4 = 16 tiles, containing the numbers 1-8 twice

    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(quadSize * quadSize);

    // add  number twice (1,1,2,2, ....)
    int num = 0;
    boolean first = false;
    while (values.size() < quadSize * quadSize) {
        if (!first) {
            num++;
        }
        values.add(num);
        first = !first;
    }

    // Shuffle the values (random order)
    Collections.shuffle(values);

    // fill into two-dimensional array
    int[][] fieldArray = new int[quadSize][quadSize];
    int index = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        fieldArray[index / quadSize][index % quadSize] = value;
        index++;
    }
```

Output using your print method:

```
[5] [7] [1] [6] 
[2] [3] [8] [3] 
[6] [8] [5] [1] 
[4] [2] [7] [4]
```