# Java while loop variable jumps for initial value

Tags: java, eclipse, math, while-loop

For the following simple `while` loop, once in every 5 runs, I get a list of wrong values for x, as if the values jump suddenly:

```
package test;
public class test_old {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    double r0 = 0.1;
    double r = 10; 
    double k = 0.05; 
    double x = 0; 
    double Tt = 0;
    double T = 0;
    while (Tt<=30) {
        double xi = Math.random();
        T = Math.log(1/xi)/(k*x + r0 + r);
        Tt = Tt + T;
        x = x + 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }   
}
}
```

Instead of getting 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, .. etc (usually around 4 values until Tt is bigger than 30), I sometimes get a list of x values that seems to go on for ever starting at for example 89462.0, or 19945.0. The list of x values is correctly incremented by 1, but it never stops. 
I am a beginner using Eclipse.
Thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: can you explain the purpose of this?

Comment: It always ends for me, usually at about 700...

Comment: Maybe double xi = Math.random(); has something with it. Print out what xi you you get and what is Tt value at the end of each loop, maybe you will discover your problem.

Comment: This is not reproducible for me. I get about 730 iterations.

Comment: NOT REPRODUCIBLE... I too am getting 730 iterations....

Comment: I ran it 100.000 times and max x was 1011.0

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. Mathematically `T` is always positive so `Tt` will eventually add up to over 30, however many iterations it take.

Comment: the purpose is something more complicated, but i stripped it down to show the error. i have tried printing out xi, all seems normal there. i will try on another pc and installation of eclipse. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Math.random () give values 0.0<=v<1.0
so if random gives you something like

```
v=0.99999999, log(1/v)=0.00000000001...
```

continue the calculation Tt=0+0.00000000001 will take like forever to be >30
just to test replace

```
 double xi = Math.random();
```

by

```
 double xi = 0.999999999999;
```

and run again
I don't know why this happen but it seems that the random gives you values like 0.9999...

so to avoid this you have to insure that random gives you smaller value
you can use this post
[Math.random() explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Comment: interestingly i have the same behavior with xi = 0.99999; thanks for the post, very useful.