# Java - getting a random number from 100 to 999

Tags: java

Please tell me whether I am correct or not with the following line.

```
int x = ((int)(Math.random() * 100000)) % 1000;
```

This line always give me a `3` digit number `100` to `999` ?

Is there an easier way to type this out? Did I over complicate this code?

Comment: There's an answer to your question here: [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: What prevents to get numbers between 0 and 100?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a better way to get random numbers, and that's with `java.util.Random`.  `Math.random()` returns a double (floating-point) value, but based on your request of a 3-digit number, I'm going to assume that what you really want is an integer.  So here's what you do.

```
// initialize a Random object somewhere; you should only need one
Random random = new Random();

// generate a random integer from 0 to 899, then add 100
int x = random.nextInt(900) + 100;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Just curious; why use 900 + 100 instead of just 1000?

Comment: @Jaaavaaaaa That would give you a random number from 0 to 999, but you said you wanted 100 to 999.

Comment: Which is why you add 100 after the random number is generated. And not inside brackets.

Answer (score 6):

You are not correct. That can produce numbers under `100`. The most familiar way is `random.nextInt(900)+100`. Here `random` is an instance of `Random`.

Before Java 7 there was no reason to create more than one instance of `Random` in your application for this purpose. Now there's no reason to have any, as the best way is

```
int value = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns value between `0.0`(*including*) and `1.0`(*excluding*) *say* it returns `0.05013371..` (*for example*)  than your method will do the following operation,

```
0.05013371.. * 100000 = 5013.371...
(int) 5013.371... = 5013
5013 % 1000 = 13 // Incorrect
```

But other *way around* you can still use `Math.random()` in a different way to solve this,

```
int upperBound = 999;
int lowerBound = 100;
int number = lowerBound + (int)(Math.random() * ((upperBound - lowerBound) + 1));
```

Explanation,

```
100 + (int)((Number >= 0.0 and  < 1.0) * (999 - 100)) + 1;
100 + (int)((Number >= 0.0 and  < 1.0) * (899)) + 1;
```

**MIN** This can return,

```
100 + (int)(0.0 * (899)) + 1;
100 + 0 + 1
101
```

**MAX** This can return,

```
100 + (int)(0.9999.. * (899)) + 1;
100 + 898 + 1 
999
```

*NOTE* : You can change *upper* and *lower* bound accordingly to get required results.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the code. It can return numbers less than 100 as well. The following link [Math.random() explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained) has the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you did here is appropriate. You should create a `Random` object instead.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(900) + 100;
```

Now `randomNumber` must be three digit.

I wrote a program to test whether your method is correct:

```
int x = 0;
int count = 0;
do {
    x = ((int)(Math.random() * 100000)) % 1000;
    count++;
} while (Integer.toString(x).length() == 3);
System.out.println ("Finished after " + count + " tries");
```

And it says "Finished after 4 tries", which means that your method is not correct.