# Java inbuilt utility for generating a random sequence of numbers

Tags: java, utility

Is there any inbuilt utility in java that I can use to genrate random numbers ? The format is xxxxxxxxxx and max limit of 10 numbers.

Comment: could please clarify "The format is xxxxxxxxxx and max limit of 10 numbers." statement

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` which returns number between 0 to 1. You can multiply any 1000000000 for getting 10 digit random number.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*100000000000)
```

Check out [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) , specially [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) and [`Math.floor()` for rounding off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Comment: This is an unsafe way to get a random integer; some results will be more likely than others due to the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  Use the [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) method to generate uniform random integers.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) class.

For example:

```
int randomNumber;
Random rand = new Random();
randomNumber = rand.nextInt(1000000000);
```

This will generate a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1000000000 (exclusive)

edit:
It's definitely worth mentioning that `nextInt()` does not require an argument, and if none is provided it will choose a random number between 0 (again, inclusive) and 2^32 (also exclusive).

Comment: @Stephan Bendy Right.... you can also set start for random number generation using.. setSeed(Long long) method....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that... setting the seed will not make the initial value equal to the seed you entered, but rather make it so that any time you call a series of random numbers with a particular seed the exact same series of numbers will be generated.

Comment: yes you are right @Stephan...

Comment: for generating random number in range you can search for "Generating random integers in a range with Java" on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The question does not describe what format is `xxxxxxxxxx`. But you can always use the `Random` class to generate a random number within a specified range. In case you have a specific format of sequence of characters and numbers then you have to merge based on the format.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGenerator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random random = new Random();
      long randomInt = random.nextInt(999999999);
      System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt);
   }
}
```

Alternately you can use the `UUID` class. A `UUID` represents a 128-bit value

For example:

```
String randomNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```