# Set parameters for Math.random

Tags: java

Are you able to set parameters for Math.random?

```
for (Node car : cars) 
    car.setTranslateX(car.getTranslateX() -  11); 
 if (Math.random() <= 0.06 ) {
    cars.add(spawnCar()); 
    cars.add(SpawnzCar());}
    checkState(); 
    }
```

I would like Math.random to return a number between 0.02 and 0.06

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math.random() explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like Math.random to return a number between 0.02 and 0.06

Why not just do

```
0.02 + 0.04 * Math.random();
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() is basically a convenience method that uses a single instance of Random. If you want more flexibility, you should use a Random instance instead. But as James_D mentioned, setting a minimum range is usually done by adding the minimum to the random number.

Answer (score 0):

To get a random uniformly distributed number between real numbers a and b, you can always try

```
a + (b - a) r
```

where r is the random number between 0 and 1 you have from Math.random(). No need to put them as parameters.