# display different random numbers on buttons in android

Tags: java, android, random

I have 10 buttons (like calculator does) displaying digits from 0 to 9.

The problem is that I want to display unique random numbers on each button every time when I press a button. How can I achieve this behavior?

My code is:

```
public void generate(View view) {
    Random rand=new Random();
    int number=rand.nextInt(10);

    but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

    but3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    but4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    but5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    but6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    but7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    but8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    but9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    but0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
    but1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    String mynumber=String.valueOf(number);

    but2.setText(a);

    but3.setText(mynumber);
    but4.setText(mynumber);
    but5.setText(mynumber);
    but6.setText(mynumber);
    but7.setText(mynumber);
    but8.setText(mynumber);
    but9.setText(mynumber);
    but0.setText(mynumber);
    but1.setText(mynumber);
    but2.setText(mynumber);
```

Comment: Could you show use some code you already have? How have you defined the buttons, are you using ButterKnife?

Comment: I am not using butterknife

Comment: Fill a list with numbers from 0 to 9, shuffle and iterate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Unique Random Numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115722/generating-unique-random-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible.

**How**:

- find your button. Event: **onCreate**
- add onClickListener event to your button.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.button_component =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_component);
    this.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // RANDOM YOUR NUMBER.               
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

check complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

```
int randomWithRange(int min, int max){
   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

Comment: Please put the complete answer as an answer. And how does this guarantee uniqueness?