# Returning the value of an array while creating a calling method

Tags: java, arrays, variables, random, callback

**Program problem:** Declare an array to hold eight integers. Use a for loop to add eight random integers, all in the range from 50 to 100, inclusive, to this array. Duplicates are okay. Next, pass the array to a method that sorts the array and returns another array containing only the largest and smallest elements in the original array. Print these two values in main. Then use a for each loop to display all elements of the sorted array on one line separated by a single space. This latter loop should also count the odd and even numbers in the array and determine the sum of all elements in the array.

Sample output:

```
The lowest element is 59
The highest element is 96
Here is the array
59 64 76 77 80 88 91 96 
Evens: 5, odds: 3
Total: 631
```

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X {

    private static Random rand;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] randomEight = numbers();
        System.out.println("Here is the array");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomEight)); 
        System.out.println();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static int[] numbers(){
     for (int x = 1; x <= 8; x++){
    //Random rand;
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
        int[] randomEight =  {randomNum};
        //(50)(Math.random() * 101); 

        return randomEight;
        }
//  int[] randomEight;
    return null;
    }
}
```

**Code issues:** I can figure out most of it, but I am having trouble return the value of the array in a random set of 8 integers that range between (50-100). My code keeps generating an error output. I might be overthinking the whole situation, but could someone guide me or give me an idea. The rest of it is easy to figure out and I might updated the code in the future.

Comment: you shouldn't return within the first iteration of your loop. you should wait until the loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code as explained below:

(1) You did not instantiate the `Random` class which is causing the `NullPointerException`, so create the object for the `Random` class using `new` operator like `Random rand = new Random()`

(2) You need to declare the array before the `for` loop and insert random number to each element

(3) Array indexes start from 0, so you need to access the elements of the array like `randomEight[0]`, `randomEight[1]`, etc.. till `randomEight[7]`, so your loop becomes `for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)`

```
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] randomEight = numbers();
        System.out.println("Here is the array");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomEight)); 
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] numbers(){
        int[] randomEight =  new int[8];
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
            randomEight[x] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50;
        }
        return randomEight;
    }
```

Comment: Added that and its still not returning the value.

Comment: you can have a look at the above code along with the steps explaining the issues

Comment: Yes, this definitely works now! Would adding a math.random be more efficient that the random rand? I feel like it would condense the code a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare an array to hold eight integers.
int[] randNums = new int[8];

//Use a for loop to add eight random integers, all in the range from 50 to 100, inclusive, to this array. Duplicates are okay.
Random rand = new Random(); // <-- You forgot to instantiate Random
for (int i = 0; i < randNums.length; i++) {
    randNums[i] = rand.nextInt((100 - 50) + 1) + 50; // <-- I suggest you put the random int directly to the element to simplify it and avoid more issues
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Would adding the math.random also be another option instead of random rand?

Comment: @A.B. Sure! For reference you can read more about `Math.random()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained). Kindly click the check if this answer worked out for you. Thank you.