# Randomly generating strings

Tags: java, string, random

I was wondering if there is a way to randomly print strings. I have this code where I have bushes represented by "( )" and rocks represented by ".". Now I want these to print out according to a random int in a different class. However they just print in one straight line. I was wondering if there is an easy way to make them all randomly generate. So instead of looking like this ( ) ( ) ( ) ( )..
they look more like this ( )     .   ( )  .     ( )   ( ). Thanks a lot for whoever takes the time to respond.

With a final output of

```
           ^
          /|\
   . (  ) /|\    .   (  )     ( )
```

Program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ForestRandomizer {

    public static String forestGen()
    {
            String bush = "( )";
            ArrayList<String> bushes = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int n = 0; Walking.bushesInArea > n; n++)
            {
                bushes.add(bush);
            }

            String rock = ".";
            ArrayList<String> rocks = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int n = 0; Walking.rocksInArea > n; n++)
            {
                rocks.add(rock);
            }


            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < bushes.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print(bushes.get(i) + "  ");
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < rocks.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print(rocks.get(i) + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Utilize [`Math.random()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained)

Comment: Generating random values is a very common and basic task. Have you done any research or made any attempt yet?

Comment: Don't create `bushes` and `rocks` create an `ArrayList` mixing them

Comment: @J.N. Why does it matter if it's a school assignment? This question matches the sites criteria.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 - this explains it pretty well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions .

"Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" - He didn't.

Comment: @J.N. He showed code, told us the exact problem, what he got as his output, and what he wanted as his output. His question was pretty exact...

Comment: @theProgrammer101 - Nope, he asking for a way to *randomly* generate them, without showing any attempt to do so on his own.

Comment: He doesn't know how to, that's what this site is for. If he knew how to, he wouldn't have asked this question. The OP must just not know about the `Math.random` or `Random` methods. This is why we tell him what they are. He has shown effort by producing his code, so I don't see what else is necessary in his post.

Comment: An simple attempts from OPs would have give him [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: @J.N. i did actually

Comment: @BrandonWhite i tried to use the math.random

Comment: @theProgrammer101 i know about the math.random code but I could not see a way to use that to scramble the order. Thank you all who helped me.

Comment: @AxelH im not trying to generate a random number im trying to rearrange and array in a random order

Comment: @IsaiahMitchell And how do you think you will get a random order in an array ? With a random index may ? Which is a random number with a range `[0... array.length]`

Comment: @AxelH i would run into out of bounds errors and i dont want to deal with that. I got the Collections.shuffle that works a lot easier than that. When i know there is an easier way then i come here.

Comment: No you won't .... `new Random(),nextInt(array.length)` would give you have value between 0 and `array.length` (exclude). This is some simple code that you should be able to do yourself. Yes `shuffle` is simpler but you could do it without a List way simpler, just like the other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program is a little rough... but it gets the job done. I have put the line-by-line explanation using comments. This program prints rocks and bushes in random places on the bottom row, and also prints a tall tree, which takes up 4 rows. Here's the program:

```
String[] choices = {"() ",".  "}; //choices holds 2 members, () and .
Random rand = new Random();       //creates random method
int place = rand.nextInt(10);     // this is for the tree
for (int j = 0; j<4; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                //executes the following loop 10 times
        if (j==3){                                //makes rocks and bushes print only on bottom line
            int NumberOfAnswers = choices.length;     //holds value of number of members in choices
            int pick = rand.nextInt(NumberOfAnswers); // picks random int 0 or 1
            String finalChoice = choices[pick];       //"finalChoice" is either member 0 or 1 of choices
            System.out.print(finalChoice);            // prints "finalChoice"
        } else {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        if (i == place && j == 0) {                 //if it's the designated place and the top row...
            System.out.print(" ^  ");               //...print the top of the tree
        } else if (i==place && (j == 1||j == 2)) {  //if it's the designated place in the 2nd or 3rd rows...
            System.out.print("/|\\ ");              //...print the body of the tree
        } else if (i == place && j == 3){           //if its the designated place and the last row
            System.out.print(" |  ");               //...print the base of the tree
        }
    }   
    System.out.println();                         //start a new line
}
```

And 2 examples of the output:

-------------1-------------

```
    ^                             
   /|\                            
   /|\                            
.   |  () .  () .  .  () .  .  .
```

-------------2-------------

```
                         ^        
                        /|\       
                        /|\       
() .  () () .  .  .  ()  |  () ()
```

Comment: Okay so I implemented the Collections.shuffle(); method and I got the output I desired. Now if I wanted to add a tree how would I do that. Since trees are taller and require more lines. Thats why in the first code i have 3 lines because the trees are like this      ^                                                       
                                                                           /|\                                     
                                                                           /|\

Comment: well basically what i was doing before was just printing /|\ but with \\ because I know its an escape charcter. But how would i be able to print it on more than one line to make it look like a tree and still have the bushes rocks and trees randomly generate.

Comment: not exactly like that. I revised the question to show the final output that I desire. However with what you gave me I'm sure I can figure it out. Instead of a birds eye view which is kind of what you have im going for more of a side view or first person in a way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to just add everthing to a single `ArrayList` and then use `Collections.shuffle()` on that list.

For example:

```
public static String forestGen(int numberBushes, int numberRocks) {
    String bush = "( )";
    String rock = ".";
    ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>(numberBushes + numberRocks);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberBushes; i++) {
        elements.add(bush);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberRocks; i++) {
        elements.add(rock);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(elements);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String element : elements) {
        sb.append(element).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Creates outputs like

```
. ( ) . ( ) . ( ) ( ) . ( )
. ( ) . ( ) ( ) ( ) ( ) . . 
( ) ( ) . ( ) ( ) ( ) . . .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but how would i go about adding something with multiple lines. Since a tree would be 3 lines im not sure how to randomly put it in between the bushes and rocks.