# How does Math.random() EXACTLY work in Java?

Tags: java

I recently came across the

> Math.random( )

class in Java. (And) I was wondering about the class. For example, I'm trying to write a dice game that needs random numbers from 1 to 6 each "roll". This is where math.random( ) comes in. This line of code:

```
int random_num = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

CAN generate random numbers between 1 to 6.

My problem lies at

```
(Math.random() * 6)
```

here.

I know how this code works, how Math.random() generates a double value between 0.0 to 1.0. And how it multiplied by 6, and was rounded in the end.

I was however, puzzled why a random number (say 0.78396954122) multiplied by 6 could become a random number between 1 to 6. Supposedly the random number  0.78396954122  multiplied by 6, is always 6, right? There's no way a  2.78396954122  can suddenly pop up!

I'm a complete noob at Java and would appreciate if you could help explain this.

Thanks...in advance!

Comment: No, 0.78396954122 * 6 is not 6.

Comment: @JackFlamp it's _truncated_ rather than _rounded_ so therefore it will never be rounded _up_

Comment: @Aominè you are right. my bad. deleting...

Comment: I think you might be also interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained

Comment: Are you asking why a number in the range 0.0 to 1.0, when multiplied by 6, ends up in the range 0.0 to 6.0?

Comment: Literally the only thing I can think of that got you to conclude that 0.78396954122 * 6 = 6, is that the `int` cast will somehow round up the `double` to 1, and therefore always be 6 when multiplied. This is not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was however, puzzled why a random number (say 0.78396954122) multiplied by 6 could become a random number between 1 to 6. Supposedly the random number 0.78396954122 multiplied by 6, is always 6, right?

No. 0.78396954122 * 6 is 4.70381724732 which when truncated by `(int)` becomes 4 which then becomes 5 when the `+ 1` is done.

Similarly, `Math.random` might return 0.2481654 which when multiplied by 6 is 1.4889924, which `(int)` truncates to 1, and then becomes 2 thanks to the `+ 1`.

If it were, say, 0.0485847 * 6, that would be 0.2915082, which `(int)` truncates to 0, which becomes 1 thanks to the `+ 1`.

The lowest value `Math.random` will ever return is 0.0, which is truncated to 0 by `(int)`. 0 * 6 is 0, which becomes 1 after the `+ 1`. The highest value `Math.random` will ever return is 0.99999999(etc) (e.g.,. it will be `< 1`). Multiplying that by 6 gives us 5.999999(etc) which is truncated to 5 by `(int)`, and then turned into 6 by `+ 1`.

So that's how we get the range 1-6 from that code.

Answer (score 3):

**Math.random()**

It generates a random number between 0.0 to 1.0(always less then 1.0).So,in your problem as you said that  you want to generate random number between `1 to 6` that is why you have multiplied it by 6, so that any random number the function will return will be multiplied by 6 and then + 1 ,so that it always stay between 1-6 .

And like you said ,  0.78396954122 * 6 is 6 then you are wrong in calculation here,

0.78396954122 * 6 is 4.7 which will be rounded off to 4  by the `(int)`. This is called **casting** in java,and at last it will become 4+1=5

That is why you get a number between 1-6 by this

Comment: I should've said I knew what casting is...but anyways, thank you for answering. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is simple math:

- Math.rand() generates a floating point number, say `x`, in the interval [0,1[, by definition
- multiplying `x` by 6 makes it in the interval [0,6[
- converting it to `int` is a truncation (almost retaining the integer part of the original number), so the value is either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5
- then adding one give either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6.

> how Math.random() generates a double value between 0.0 to 1.0.

Generating pseudo-random numbers is a tricky thing. Java specs does not define how this is implemented, so we can't tell you how it works. But if you want to know how to generate pseudo-random numbers then may be a good entry is [Wikipedia PRNG page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Thanks for answering! :)