# How to get random numbers with different probabilities in different ranges in java?

Tags: java, random

I want to get an integer random number between 0 and 100 with different probabilities in different ranges.

For example I want the probability of values between 0 and 20 to be `0.5` and the probability of values between 21 and 80 to be `0.4` and the probability of values between 81 and 100 to be `0.1`.

Is there any method or class in Java or any library for Java to do it? If not, how can I do it myself?

Comment: Write some code and show us.

Comment: No Rafał Sokalski. that post is looking for a way to have different probabilities for different values. but I am looking for a way to have different probabilities for different ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to have an extra random number determining the range it should generate:

```
int getRandomNumberWithRangeProbability() {
    double range = Math.random();

    if (range < 0.5) {
        return randomWithRange(0, 20);
    } else if (range < 0.9) {
        return randomWithRange(21, 80);
    } else {
        return randomWithRange(81, 100);
    }
}

int randomWithRange(int min, int max) {
    int range = (max - min) + 1;
    return (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

A small test can be found [here](https://tio.run/##jVLfj9JAEH7vXzHxaSuwgUtMTkESNT4YD2Mk0Qfjw9LO9Rbb3WZ3ijbm/nZuti1Q4CQMD1vm5zffN2u1UaN1@nu71UVpHcGaHbIinct3zqn6TnuaRmex/7gXqnzG68mhKuQHm@eYkHV@GkVltcp1AkmuvIeF0gb@RRGwdQFPivjZWJ1CwWGxJKdN9vMXKJf5mLOhtYBk9skQZujm4JRJbfGlKlboPLwFg39gv8dsLuJptCuEe@tAaEOgOXE85WcGkzEbfw4G8T4v2FFfqdJUZEjfes4fmh74f4ZfnV2plc411SLuj2NudjiHcGdNNofEVoYY5tGos3Fn0Z11xIr4QgYrgemljKRVRRzUkZmzVclkv68FwmgOOIRetAHNUd7ujE3eUX405GpAeNOtJzE4lkhccJCtsWXtCQtpK5Ilq0u5ESiZ2M/I3MEAXvBvAI3ru8orbAjdFT@2s7uH6zeKcHc3QdarFOohSi2fHgbuM@SLWCh6kK0QR2ej70G0OTMYy1enOzmkyplOwf1MMR7CzbiPHjD3eNLs9ZXNbiZDuH2m21XFt1zMZ37E5GUiTzsEX6HNsAkW6m8fdZffMCg4BqOQGsScHAZ2yEKjOBxNj2h42ZaHCi6cdtAet9sn).

<sup>Credits to [AusCBloke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998299/auscbloke) for the [`randomWithRange()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961881/479156) method.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You should get random in each range and then get another random between 0 and 1 and treat in your interest
Good Luck
*ETG*

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this way don't know if there is any inbuilt function for doing this or not

1. So Make a function that will return random between two integers.
2. make a variable probable having random value of 1-10
3. Satisfy these condition

> ```
> if(probable>=0 &&  probable<=5){
>           random = getUniqueRandom(0, 20);
>
>       }
>       else if(probable>=6 &&  probable<=9) {
>           random = getUniqueRandom(21, 80);
>
>       }
>       else if (probable == 10) {
>           random = getUniqueRandom(81, 100);
>
>       }
> ```

Here is the working implementation

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Solution  {
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pro1 = 0, pro2 =0, pro3 =0;
        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        int probable = getUniqueRandom(0, 10);
        int random = 0;

        if(probable>=0 &&  probable<=5){
            random = getUniqueRandom(0, 20);
            pro1++;
        }
        else if(probable>=6 &&  probable<=9) {
            random = getUniqueRandom(21, 80);
            pro2++;
        }
        else if (probable == 10) {
            random = getUniqueRandom(81, 100);
            pro3++;
        }

        //System.out.println(random);
    }
        System.out.println("Checked 10000 Times.\n0-20 Found: "+pro1);
        System.out.println("21-80 Found: "+pro2);
        System.out.println("81-100 Found: "+pro3);
    }
    static int getUniqueRandom(int min, int max){
        int num = r.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
        return num;
    }
}
```