# How do I generate random doubles in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

My goal is to ask the user for an array length and generate a list of random doubles to fill that array out. I don't understand how to get Math.random into my array. I started with a different approach and scrapped it. Why does double random = Math.random() * array; not import a random generator into my array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Average
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    /*Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your array size: ");
    int size = in.nextInt();
    int[] awnser = new int[size]; */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");

    double[] array = new double[scanner.nextDdouble()];
    double random = Math.random() * array;
    System.out.println(array.length);

    }
  }
```

Comment: You're trying to multiply a `Math.random()` by an array? What are you trying to do with this line?  Are you trying to populate the array with random numbers?

Comment: how can you instantiate a new array of doubles passing it a non-integer size?

Comment: ["*I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.*" - Charles Babbage](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/charles_babbage_141832)

Comment: you need to use a for to generate the doubles from 0 to the number that the user put , i recomend to read an integer or at least parse the double to integer value and i dont know if the compiler let you instantiate an array with a double number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does double random = Math.random() * array; not import a random generator into my array?

You have misunderstood how this class works. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explained) is a good explanation of what this class does. What I believe you are trying to do is something along the lines of:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    //create an array with the size entered by the user
    double[] array = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
    //populate the array with doubles
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = rand.nextDouble();
    }
```

`nextDouble` returns a pseudorandom number between 0 and 1.0, so you'll need to multiply it by your upper bound. (i.e if 100 was your upper limit `rand.nextDouble() * 100;`)

(Make sure to `import` the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class)

Comment: When I compile and print this array it prints more than numbers do I need to create a max and min?

Answer (score 5):

With your current solution you'd need to iterate with a counter starting from 0 and ending before the given size, assigning each array element with a `nextDouble` invocation.

Multiplying an array object by a number is just not supported in Java.

Here's a Java-8 idiom that you may favor instead:

```
DoubleStream
    .generate(ThreadLocalRandom.current()::nextDouble)
    .limit(yourGivenSize)
    .toArray();
```

This will give you a `double[]` of size `yourGivenSize`, whose elements are generated randomly.

Comment: Here's a better Java 8 idiom: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().doubles(yourGivenSize).toArray()`

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8+

You can use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) with the [`Random#doubles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#doubles--) method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
//...
double[] randoms = ThreadLocalRandom.current().doubles(10).toArray();
//Generate 10 random doubles

double[] randoms = ThreadLocalRandom.current().doubles(10, 0, 5).toArray();
//Generate 10 random doubles between 0 (inclusive) and 5 (exclusive)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [`Arrays#setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-double:A-java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction-)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[10];
        Arrays.setAll(array, i -> Math.random());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

**Output of a sample run:**

> [0.1182317810027168, 0.9437573020895418, 0.2690105524813662,
> 0.6771923722130754, 0.04893586074165357, 0.42483010937765653, 0.16310798731469023, 0.2541941051963008, 0.9838342001474454, 0.8595732419001068]

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new double[10];
        
        array = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                    .mapToDouble(i -> Math.random())
                    .toArray();
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = new Random().doubles(10).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = ThreadLocalRandom.current().doubles(10).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 10;
        double[] array = new double[SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            array[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] array = Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(10).toArray(Double[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

### Alternatively,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(10).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, what is the range of the values you are trying to get inside your array ? In any case I think this should achieve what you are trying to do, I am using a command line argument here to supply the array length, feel free to change that back to a scanner.

```
int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

double[] array = new double[arrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    array[i] = Math.random() * arrayLength;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

To generate random values of a specific range:

```
Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your original idea to calculate the amount of times you loop to generate your random double numbers. As you know array index (or positions) starts at zero. So I used a for loop to begin at zero and once the number is generated this line: list[i] = num; places the random number into the first index(position) of the array and continues until it reaches the size the user specified.

```
package stack;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter a number");

    int size = input.nextInt();
       Double[] list = new Double[size];

       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            Double num = Math.random();
            list[i] = num;
       }
     System.out.println(list.length);
    }
    }

/*  for(int i = 0; i< list.length; i++){
     System.out.println(list[i]);  }
*/
```

I also included if you want to check the array contents. I created another for loop with the same concept as the first loop by checking each index(position) and display them.