# How to randomize two players to "X" and to "O?

Tags: java, string, user-interface, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe game and I have randomily assign player 1 one to either "X" or "O" and same with player 2. I have no clue how to start the code

It should make player one either X or O and make player 2 whatever is left over from player 1

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Give at least the way you represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number between for example 0 and 1 by using a random object or the Math.Random() function.

Based on the random number you can select via if and else, which letter "X"/"O" the first player will get.
The second player can then be assigned what is left.

Have look on Math.Random:
[Math.random() explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explanation)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RandomTicTacToeSymbols {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] symbols = {"X" , "O"};

        int randomIndex = (int) Math.round( Math.random());
        String playerOneSymbol = symbols[randomIndex];
        String playerTwoSymbol = symbols[(randomIndex+1) % 2];

        System.out.println(String.format("Player 1 -> %s - Player 2 -> %s", playerOneSymbol, playerTwoSymbol) );
    }
}
```