# I wanted to make an random image generator but it does not work

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So i have made this program and i wanted it t create a 8 by 8 sized image with only Black and White but it does only display a white color instead of randomly spread black and white. Here is my code. If someone can help that'd be great :D

```java
package de.gamingengine.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {

        int width = 8;
        int height = 8;
        Color c = null;

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        File f = null;

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

                int blackorwhite = (int)Math.random()*10;

                if(blackorwhite >= 5) {

                    c = Color.BLACK;

                } else if(blackorwhite < 5){

                    c = Color.WHITE;

                }

                img.setRGB(x, y, c.getRGB());

            }

        }

        try {

            f = new File("C:\\Users\\Linus\\Desktop\\Out.png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error: " + e);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the precedence of operators. Here :

```
(int) Math.random() * 10
```

First you will cast the result of `Math.random()` to `int`. Since this method returns values from `[0,1)`, you cast it to `int` so it is always 0 and then you multiply it by 10 but it is still 0 in the end.

Change your code to :

```
int blackorwhite = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

Comment: @GamingEngine please do accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Cast to int after multiply:

```
(int)(Math.random()*11)
```

See [Random with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961788/math-random-explanation/16624834)

> ```
>  int range = (max - min) + 1;     
>     return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

While all the answers mentioning operator precedence and the that the cast must be on the complete expression are correct, I like to point out that there is a better option for this specific case:

Use `Random.nextInt(int bound)` instead.

It returns a pseudo-random number in the range `[0...bound>`. This method is [more efficient and mathematically more correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738651/1428606) due to less bias (but I doubt this makes much difference for your use case).

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int blackorwhite = random.nextInt(10); // Look, no cast

        // Rest of the code as-is
        ...
    }
}
```

PS: I think your code would be even clearer if you just used `nextInt(2)` or  `nextBoolean()`.